# Whats the best way to declare pointers for 2D arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I'm learning how to use 2D Arrays in C while also learning pointers. Whats the best way to declare a pointer for a 2D array?

I'm doing it this way

```c
    int nums[2][3] = {
            {5, 4, 3},
            {3, 0, 9}
    };
    int *numsptr = nums;
    printf("%p\n", numsptr);
```

Also how can I access specific indexes through pointers?
The article I read said this.

`In general, nums[i][j] is equivalent to *(*(nums+i)+j)`

I tried doing this.

`printf("%d\n", (*numsptr + 1) + 2);`

Which outputs`8`(Which isn't in the 2D array)

Comment: Also doing `int *numsptr = &nums;` doesn't change anything.

Comment: For a 2D array you need an `int**` pointer, not `int*` which is just 1D.

Comment: ((*numsptr + 1) + 2) that you are using is not the same as the article indicated which would be  *(*(numsptr + 1) + 2)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I generally would

```
numsptr[r*cols + c]
```

Which would be equivalent to

```
nums[r][c]
```

If you want to dynamically find `cols` rather than hardcode, the following expression can be used

```
sizeof(nums[0])/sizeof(nums[0][0])
```

The reason this

```
printf("%d\n", (*numsptr + 1) + 2);
```

prints `8` is because `*numsptr` returns the value at `nums[0]`, which is `5`, adds `1`, and then adds `2` (which is `8`);

Comment: Just as a note, in this particular case that's probably right, but that assumes a lot about how the structure is laid out internally. `int* nums[2]` could be a whole different thing even if superficially similar.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I access specific indexes through pointers?

Depends on the pointer. You can declare a pointer to an array of 3 `ints`, that way you can just access the pointer almost as-if the array (but watch out for `sizeof`):

```
int (*ptr)[3] = nums;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
       printf("[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, ptr[i][j]);
       // since you mentioned `a[b] == *(a + b)` some alternatives:
       // or printf("[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, *(*(ptr + i) + j));
       // or printf("[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, *(ptr[i] + j));
       // or printf("[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, (*(ptr + i))[j]);
       // or pls dont printf("[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, i[ptr][j]);
    }
}
```

You use a pointer to the array of 2 arrays of 3 `int`s. Semantically, it's a different thing and you have to first dereference the pointer:

```
int (*var)[2][3] = &nums;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        printf("[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, (*var)[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Because elements in an array are laid in memory continuously, you can alias the array with a pointer to `int` and do the row/column arithmetic yourself:

```
int *p = (int*)nums;
for (int i = 0; i < 2 * 3; ++i) {
    printf("[%d] = %d\n", i, p[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        printf("[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, p[i * 3 + j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several flavors of pointers to multidimensional arrays.

There’s the pointer that comes from applying the `&` operator to the array expression.  Given the declaration

```
int nums[2][3];
```

then the expression `&nums` yields a pointer of type `int (*)[2][3]` - “pointer to 2-element array of 3-element array of `int`”.  You’d declare it as

```
int (*ptr)[2][3] = &nums;
```

You’d index into it as `(*ptr)[i][j]`.  Since the `[]` operator has higher precedence than the unary `*` operator, you need to explicitly group the `*` with `ptr` for it to work properly.

There’s the pointer that comes from the “decay” rule for arrays - except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an expression of type “N-element array of `T`” will be converted (“decay”) to an expression of type “pointer to `T`” and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  So the *expression* `nums` “decays” from type “2-element array of 3-element array of `int`” (`int [2][3]`) to type “pointer to 3-element array of `int`” (`int (*)[3]`):

```
int (*ptr)[3] = nums; // no & operator
```

You’d index into this as `ptr[i][j]`.  Remember that the subscript operation `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`, so `*ptr` is the same as `ptr[0]`, so `(*ptr)[j]` is the same as `(ptr[0])[j]`.  This is probably the more commonly used form for pointers to 2D arrays.

Then there’s the double pointer `int **`, which is not actually a pointer to a 2D array, but a pointer to an array of pointers, each element of which points to the first element of another array, usually allocated like so:

```
int **ptr = malloc( 2 * sizeof *ptr );
if ( ptr )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
  {
    ptr[i] = malloc( 3 * sizeof *ptr[i] );
  }
}
```

This is an example of a “jagged” array, where the rows are not contiguous and don’t have to be the same size.  These are usually allocated dynamically.  You’d index into it as `ptr[i][j]`.